# Output Nested JSON Data to Node JS Variables

Tags: node.js, json, express

Good Day, How can i get the Data from Json and make it a variable on Nodejs? and how can i calculate the time, what is the syntax am i gonna use? I'm New to NodeJS, Thanks in Advance

> App.js

this is giving me an error on module  on my index path

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

const indexRoutes = require('./routes/index');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(indexRoutes);


app.listen(8080);
```

> Controller

```
const Schedule = require('../models/schedule');

exports.getSchedule = (req, res, next) => {
  Schedule.fetchAll(schedule => {
    res.render('index', {
      sched: schedule,
      pageTitle: 'Schedule',
      path: '/routes'
    });
  });
};
```

> Models

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const p = path.join(
  path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename),
  'data',
  'dbm_input.json'
);

const getScheduleFromFile = cb => {
  fs.readFile(p, (err, fileContent) => {
    if (err) {
      cb([]);
    } else {
      cb(JSON.parse(fileContent));
    }
  });
};

module.exports = class Schedule {
  constructor(employee_info,) {
    this.;
    this.;
    this.;
    this.;
  }

  static fetchAll(cb) {
    getScheduleFromFile(cb);
  }
};
```

> Routes

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');

const ScheduleController = require('../controller/ScheduleController');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', ScheduleController.getSchedule);

module.exports = router;
```

> JSON

```
{"652":
    {"employee_info":
            {"employee_name":""},
        "date_log":
            {
                "2017-12-31":
                {
                    "config":{
                        "shift":"R","hours_per_day":8,
                        "break_hours":1,"flexi_hours":0,
                        "grace_period":15
                    },
                    "log":{
                        "time_in":"2017-12-31 07:35:37",
                        "time_out":"2017-12-31 09:34:01",
                        "break_out":["2017-12-31 12:00:00"],
                        "break_in":["2017-12-31 13:00:00"],
                        "shift_in":"2017-12-31 16:00:00",
                        "shift_out":"2017-12-31 16:00:00",
                        "status":"present",
                        "holiday":"no",
                        "overtime":"no"}
                },
                "2017-12-29":
                    {
                        "config":{
                            "shift":"FL",
                            "hours_per_day":8,
                            "break_hours":1,
                            "flexi_hours":2,
                            "grace_period":0},
                        "log":{
                            "time_in":"2017-12-29 00:20:00",
                            "time_out":"2017-12-29 10:35:00",
                            "break_out":["2017-12-31 12:00:00"],
                            "break_in":["2017-12-31 13:00:00"],
                            "shift_in":"2017-12-29 16:00:00",
                            "shift_out":"2017-12-29 16:00:00",
                            "status":"present",
                            "holiday":"no",
                            "overtime":"no"
                    }
                },
                "2017-12-28":
                    {
                        "config":{
                            "shift":"R",
                            "hours_per_day":8,
                            "break_hours":1,
                            "flexi_hours":0,
                            "grace_period":0},
                        "log":{
                            "time_in":"2017-12-28 00:02:25",
                            "time_out":"2017-12-29 10:35:00",
                            "break_out":["2017-12-31 12:00:00"],
                            "break_in":["2017-12-31 13:00:00"],
                            "shift_in":"2017-12-28 16:00:00",
                            "shift_out":"2017-12-28 16:00:00",
                            "status":"present",
                            "holiday":"no",
                            "overtime":"no"
                            }}
                    }
                }
}
```

I've been searching for a long time seems i dont know what i should search for coz i cant see the solution for that. i just want to make the data into variables and how to calculate the time given on the data and where should i put it. and how can i loop the data when i calculated the data. I'm really noob to nodejs, give me a hand guys? Thank you in advance

Comment: use `var myjson = require('./path/to/myjson.json')` or read the file and use `JSON.parse(fileAsString);`, the recommended time/date library is `moment.js`

Comment: how can i get the integer key via constructor? and output it on ejs template?

Comment: what data do you need exactly?

Comment: I need to compute the time at config with formula and output it on the table, get the employee id and name.